# How open (switch, set) softkeyboard from service

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

How open (switch, set) softkeyboard from my service?

My application is not consist any activity. But i try open softkeyboard on trigger in my service, when alient application is onscreen.
I find in `InputMethodManager`'s method `setInputMethod`. Second argument is id of keyboard. I know it. But first argument is `IBinder`. What is IBinder argument in my application?

Add detail:

My application consist of `Service` and `InputMethodService`.

In Service - Analyzing starting application in system. In `InputMethodService` - my softkeyboard (IME). If in my Service i determine what is start right application (I dont own this application), I need to  switch current `softkeyboard` to my InputMethodService's IME. Only switch, but not open keyboard. And when user tap on editabled view in client application, system open my soft keyboard.

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Praful Bhatnagar, Short: my service analize starting of any applications in system, and i need start desired keyboard when starting right application.

Comment: ahh really sorry but I still don't understand the requirement.. can you please elaborate more on the requirement..

Comment: Add detail: My application consist from Service and InputMethodService. In Service - analising starting application in system. In InputMethodService - my softkeyboard (IME). If in my Service i determine what is start right application (I not own for this application), i need switch current softkeyboard to my InputMethodService's IME. Only switch, but not open keyboard. And when user tap on editabled view in alient appliation, system open my softkeyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution code in `Service`:

```
    ((InputMethodManager) contextService.getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).setInputMethod( null, myInputMethodId);
    ((InputMethodManager) contextService.getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInputFromWindow( null, 1, 0);
```

p.s. This work only if my application is a system (`null` in first argument in `setInputMethod` available only when my application is system).
I programmatically get system privilegies for my app with `mv /data/app/myapp.apk /system/app/myapp.apk` (basis on https://stackoverflow.com/a/14257161/1665964).