# No Progress Spinner in ProgressDialog

Tags: android, spinner, progressdialog, invisible

I am trying to create a ProgressDialog as seen in just about every app on the Play Store now. I am using the code:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ProgressDialog dialog;
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "title", "message", true, false);
            }
        });
```

I have also tried with just the 2 lines inside the Runnable (without creating a thread) from inside a fragment and no matter what I do I **can't see the spinner in the ProgressDialog**. I'm attaching a screenshot so that you can see what I mean. Somebody PLEASE help me.

Running Android 5.1.1 on a Galaxy S6, all stock OS.

**EDIT**: Imports are:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
```

[image]

Comment: show us your imports

Comment: try to remove the both `boolean` and set it VIA object call.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I tried this, and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

Check with style you use res/values/style and add new or change color

styles.xml

```
  <style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
    </style>
```

actyity

`ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProfilActivity.this,R.style.MyDialogTheme);`

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("[YOUR MESSAGE]");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true); // Check as required
    progressDialog.show();
```

Comment: This wasn't successful, it seems like just another way to do what I'm already doing...

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a fragment use getActivity() instead of this

```
            ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progressDialog.setMessage("[YOUR MESSAGE]");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true); // Check as required
            progressDialog.show();*/
```

This one work for me :)