# Why application doesn't become a system application after copying it to /system?

Tags: android, linux, nullpointerexception, android-permissions

I have an application that I need to make a system application to give it some extra permissions. I want to do that by moving it to `/system/app`. I have used `ES File Explorer` to do that. According to what I've understood, the app must be installed on `SD Card`, but even when it's so, it doesn't become a system app. Here are my attempts (Any step related to moving or modifying files is done using `ES File Explorer` ):

**- Without using SD Card:**

1. I run the application using Android Studio to install the apk on the device.
2. I open /data/app and copy the apk file.
3. I open /system/app, I paste the apk.
4. I reboot the device.
5. I find the app icon on the screen, I click it, but it is not granted system permissions. Note, if I use **cut** instead of **copy** in step 2, when I reboot the device I don't find the app icon, although it's apk is there in `/system/app`.

**- When using SD Card:**

1. I run the application using Android Studio to install the apk on the device.
2. I open /data/app and cut the apk file.
3. I open /extSdcard and paste the apk file.
4. I copy the apk from /extSdCard , then paste it in  /system/app.
5. I reboot the device.In this case I find the app icon, but when I open it I get this NullPointerException Error.

**EDIT:**
**To solve the NullPointerException error, I long click the app icon in /system/app, select properties, click on change beside permissions, check everything under read, check only owner checkbox under write, and uncheck everything under execute, then I click OK. 
The problem now is after rebooting the device, I don't find the app icon, although it's apk is in /system/app and /extSdCard/android/data with size around 47 MB, but when I open the app manager from settings, I find it with sd card icon (not android app icon) and with size 0.0 B, why is this happening?**

How can I properly make the app as a system app?

Comment: Have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256687/how-to-make-my-application-system

Comment: @AmitKumar thanks, I followed this tutorial except for the step that says that I need to enable Up to root check box, as it doesn't appear in the app. After rebooting the device the app icon doesn't show on the screen. However, I found the app in SD card with size equal to 47 MB, I found it on /system/app with the same size too. But, when I open app manager from settings I found the app with sd card icon (not android app icon) with size 0.00 B, what does this mean? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that we must change both app folder and apk file permissions using `ES File Explorer`. I followed this tutorial and it worked very well:

http://howto.highonandroid.com/android-how-to-tutorials/how-to-install-user-apps-as-system-apps-on-your-android/