# Android: How to prevent uninstalling my app or make it system app?

Tags: android, uninstallation

Our company issues free `tablet` with our `application` pre-installed. We are curious that our app should not be able to `uninstall` from our `tablet`. I have found many related questions but couldn't find any proper solution. I know its not that much possible because a user has full rights to `uninstall` any `application` but as we are providing free `tablet` against our `application` maybe we can put our app as a `system app` or we can `lock` it. 
Any help would be appreciated if it is possible.

Comment: Did you check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256687/how-to-make-my-application-system and the link in the first answer?

Comment: you can create a custom firmware for that tablet, you can use root to install your app as a system app.

Comment: I am wondering there are many many app lock apps on the play store How these are working then (without rooting)? like this one. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty Sure, you can contact the manufacturer of the Company's Tablet like Samsung, etc.. and tell them your Business Requirements, This is only if by pre-installed you mean the manufacturer is the one who included your app in the device.

This can be easily done on their side.